# how create collect_list without brackets pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that I export via json to an s3, however, I need the "_source" to be generated only with the keys, without the square brackets

```py
def export_data(example):
    example = example \
            .groupby(col("_id"), col("_index")) \
            .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct(
                col("colA1"),
                col("colA2"),
                col("colA3"),
                col("colA4"),
                col("colA5"),
                col("colA6"))).alias("_source"))
    return example.select(collect_list(F.struct(col("_id"), col("_source"))).alias("hits"))

def main():
    example_export = export_data(example)

    example_export.coalesce(1) \
        .write.format('json') \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .save(
        "s3://aws-example/output/EXPORTER")
```

What I Have:

```json
{
    "hits": [
        {
            "_id": "22b9d653-c07a-46da-a929-42337f0f020d",
            "_source": [
                {
                    "colA1": "202211",
                    "colA2": "A",
                    "colA3": "020160",
                    "colA4": "MANAUS",
                    "colA5": "18",
                    "colA6": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "6fe3b950-3b09-4f11-b4d7-5e8c9aab8f3e",
            "_source": [
                {
                    "colA1": "202211",
                    "colA2": "A",
                    "colA3": "21345",
                    "colA4": "RORAIMA",
                    "colA5": "10",
                    "colA6": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need:

```json
{
    "hits": [
        {
            "_id": "22b9d653-c07a-46da-a929-42337f0f020d",
            "_source": {
                "colA1": "202211",
                "colA2": "A",
                "colA3": "020160",
                "colA4": "MANAUS",
                "colA5": "18",
                "colA6": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "6fe3b950-3b09-4f11-b4d7-5e8c9aab8f3e",
            "_source": {
                "colA1": "202211",
                "colA2": "A",
                "colA3": "21345",
                "colA4": "RORAIMA",
                "colA5": "10",
                "colA6": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you're sure that the you only have one record per unique combination of `_id` and `_index` then you don't need a `groupBy`. You can create a struct using `withColumn`.